# Which is the valid email address for our sharepoint team site's group; the one which have "onmicrosoft" in it or the one which does not have it

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, team-sites, domain, office-365-groups

I have created a new sharepoint team site as follow:-
[image]

and i got an office 365 group created for me.
now i am getting 2 different email addresses for my office 365 group and team site, as follow:-

1. When i hover over the sharepoint site name, i got this email address (without onmicrosoft) @ `HRManagers@ourcompany.com`, as follow:-

[image]

2. While if i access the office 365 group which get created automatically, from "office 365 admin" >> "Group", i got this email address (with onmicrosoft in it) @ `HRManagers@ourcompany.onmicrosoft.com`, as follow:-

[image]

**So which email address is the valid one?**

NOTE:- We have 2 domains as follow:-
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both addresses are valid; every object gets a @.onmicrosoft.com address.

Comment: so sending emails to `HRManagers@ourcompany.onmicrosoft.com` or to `HRManagers@ourcompany.com` will do the same exact thing ? and the group members will get the email at their inboxes?

Comment: can you advice on my above comment?

Comment: Yes, they'll go to the same account/object.